# JavaScript finding, displaying nodes

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

There is software which adds "powered by..." text and image to a link. In it's license it says that it's not forbidden to remove that addition. I could do it by hand, but when I refresh the page, the powered thing is added again, so I need something to hide it. There is couple ways, but I want to do it with javascript help. So here what I have in every page bottom:

[image: logo]

This is the code I can see:

```
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
<br/><br/><center><small> <a href="http://pages.ebay.com/blackthorne/" target="_blank"><img align=absbottom border=0 src="http://www.blackthornesw.com/bthome/BlackthorneB2Shade_GB.bmp"</img></a></small></center><br/><center><font face=Arial,Helvetica size=2>Powered by <a href="http://pages.ebay.com/blackthorne/" target="_blank">eBay Blackthorne 04.11.017</a></font></center>
<script>
function ErrorOff() {return true;}
window.onerror = ErrorOff;
setTimeout("document.images.eBayBig.style.display='none'",300);
</script>
```

Before this code (at the bottom of the HTML) I add javascript which I found on the internet and I get this result:
[image]

Here is full code (with javascript which I found):

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
window.onload=function(){
findcenter();
}
function findcenter()
{
nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("center");
subnode = nodes[nodes.length-1];
var link = subnode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
if(link.indexOf("pages.ebay") != -1)
{
subnode.style.display="none";
}
}
</SCRIPT>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
<br/><br/><center><small> <a href="http://pages.ebay.com/blackthorne/" target="_blank"><img align=absbottom border=0 src="http://www.blackthornesw.com/bthome/BlackthorneB2Shade_GB.bmp"</img></a></small></center><br/><center><font face=Arial,Helvetica size=2>Powered by <a href="http://pages.ebay.com/blackthorne/" target="_blank">eBay Blackthorne 04.11.017</a></font></center>
<script>
function ErrorOff() {return true;}
window.onerror = ErrorOff;
setTimeout("document.images.eBayBig.style.display='none'",300);
</script>
```

As you can see the text "Powered by..." is gone, but image still appears. How should I change this javascript that image would be gone too?

Comment: I am confused by the setTimeout, which seems to imply the image is retrieved periodically. If this  is the case, you must use setInterval, since setTimeout occurs only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by myself, if anyone can optimize it somehow I would be thankful, here is mine solution:

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
window.onload=function(){
findcenter();
}
function findcenter()
{
nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("small");
subnode = nodes[nodes.length-1];

var link = subnode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
if(link.indexOf("pages.ebay") != -1)
{
subnode.style.display="none";
}

nodes2 = document.getElementsByTagName("center");
subnode2 = nodes2[nodes2.length-1];

var link2 = subnode2.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
if(link2.indexOf("pages.ebay") != -1)
{
subnode2.style.display="none";
}
}
</SCRIPT>
```